# Is there a comparison of Frameworks, Grid Systems and Boilerplates?

Tags: tools, software, css-framework

There are so much of them, how can I know what to use for a project?

Comment: The first thing you should specify is what language and what purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Well, there is a comparison of web application frameworks in a [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_application_frameworks). Also you may find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/992110/what-do-you-believe-to-be-the-best-css-grid-system-and-why) Stackoverflow post on Grid system comparison useful.

But the question is, does these comparisons make you capable of choosing the right framework? Of course Not!

As Aurelio mentions above, you need to know your goals, the language you're going to use, your constraints and you have to use the experience of an expert to choose the right solution. Things may change by you move forward using an application, you may find out you need something different, flexibility, usability and being user friendly are not included in comparisons, but you can elicit these kind of things from an expert's mind by asking more specific questions and also answering to his questions.